# Hive datatype confusion

Tags: date, datetime, hadoop, hive, timestamp

I have a large data and in that one field be like **Wed Sep 15 19:17:44 +0100 2010** and I need to insert that field in Hive.

I am getting troubled for choosing data type. I tried both timestamp and date but getting null values when loading from CSV file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data type is a String as it is text. If you want to convert it, I would suggest a TIMESTAMP. However you will need to do this conversion yourself while loading the data or (even better) afterwards.

To convert to a timestamp, you can use the following syntax:

```
CAST(FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(<date_column>,'FORMAT')) as TIMESTAMP)
```

Your format seems complex though. My suggestion is to load it as a string and then just do a simple query on the first record until you get it working.

```
    SELECT your_column as string_representation,
CAST(FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(<date_column>,'FORMAT')) as TIMESTAMP) as timestamp_representation
    FROM your_table
    LIMIT 1
```

You can find more information on the format here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

My advice would be to concat some substrings first and try to convert only the day, month, year part before you look at time and timezone et cetera.